# How to show that a Vector space is isomorphic with the range of a vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations, vector-space-isomorphism

I have the following question.

Let $V$ and $W$ be vector spaces, let T: $V \to W$ be a linear transformation, and let $B = \{v_1, v_2, ..., v_n\}$ be a basis of $V$. Prove that if $T$ is injective, then $V$ is isomorphic with $Range(T)$.

I have assumed that $T$ is injective so we know $T(v_1) = T(v_2)$, which implies that $v_1 = v_2$, and also that the $\ker(T) = \{0\}$.

I am not sure how to proceed from here.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/06Xoz.png)

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: "we know $T(v_1) = T(v_2)$": no.

Comment: I think OP meant "$T$ is injective so we know that $T(v_1)=T(v_2)\Rightarrow v_1=v_2$, which is true (definition of injectivity). I suppose the problem with using $v_1$ and $v_2$ is that they have already been defined as basis vectors, so perhaps $y_1$ and $y_2$ might be more appropriate to use here, but the concept is there.

Answer (score 1):

By definition of range, we know $T$ is surjective from $V \to $ Range($T$). So $T$ is bijective (not from $V \to W$!). All we need to check for isomorphism is see if Range($T$) is a vector space.

Since Range($T$) $\subseteq W$, checking for closure is enough. Let $w, w'$ be arbitrary in Range($T$) and $a$ be a scalar from the field of $W$. Then,

$$
\begin{align*}
aw + w' &= aT(v) + T(v') \tag{By injectivity}
\\ &= T(av) + T(v')
\\ &= T(av + v')
\\ & \in \text{Range}(T)
\end{align*}
$$
This completes the argument.

Answer (score 0):

If $f : V \to V$ is injective and $\{v_1, \dots{}, v_n\}$ is a base for $V$, then a base of $\operatorname{im} f$ is $\{f\left(v_1\right), \dots{}, f\left(v_n\right)\}$. (In general, injective linear functions map linear independent vectors to linear indipendent vectors.) Thus this subspace must coincide with the whole $V$, being $V$ finite-dimensional.

Answer (score 0):

It's fairly easy to prove that if $v_1.\dots,v_n$ is a basis of $V$, then $Tv_1,\dots,Tv_n$ spans range$(T)$. It is also easy to prove that if $T : V\to W$ is injective and $v_1,\dots,v_n$ is a linearly independent list in $V$, then $Tv_1,\dots,Tv_n$ is linearly independent in $W$.

Using these two results, we can conclude that $Tv_1,\dots,Tv_n$ is a basis of range$(T)$ and thus the dimension of range$(T)$ is the same as $V$. Now use the result that two finite dimensional vector spaces are isomorphic if and only if they have the same dimension to conclude that $V\cong \text{range}(T)$.

Or you can make an argument that $T$ is a bijection from $V\to \text{range}(T)$ to conclude that $T$ is an isomorphism.